# Trying to figure out why my debian server crashed

Tags: linux, debian, logging

I'm running physical debian server as storage, At around 21:00 yesterday he crashed, I found out the following log, from /var/log/syslog:

https://pastebin.com/NkwtH2wT

I couldn't SSH the machine, or access the web gui.
I did manage to get reply ping..
I tried to connect physical screen but all I got was a black screen..

I didn't really understand it too much.. I will be glad if someone could explain me a bit, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The output shows that `md0_resync` process was hung on the system. `md0_resync` is the process that synchronizes the members of the MD RAID devices.

Since it was hung, it is likely that one of your MD devices is failing. You can check the status of your MD with `cat /proc/mdstat`.

Comment: md0 : active raid10 sdb[23] sdw[21] sdv[22] sdu[25] sdt[18] sds[17] sdr[16] sdq[15] sdp[14] sdo[13] sdn[12] sdm[11] sdl[10] sdk[9] sdj[8] sdi[7] sdh[6] sdg[24] sdf[4] sde[3] sdd[26] sdc[1]
      21487212032 blocks super 1.2 512K chunks 2 near-copies [22/22] [UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU]
      [==>..................]  resync = 12.9% (2775966208/21487212032) finish=1510.5min speed=206451K/sec
seems like it's resync now the raid

Comment: Actually, in the log, it seems like everytime another task is blocked..

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, Just follow the link: https://www.blackmoreops.com/2014/09/22/linux-kernel-panic-issue-fix-hung_task_timeout_secs-blocked-120-seconds-problem/